# Spring validators are being ignored

Tags: spring-boot, validation

I have a function defined as follows:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping
import javax.validation.Valid

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
class MyController {

    @PostMapping
    fun someFunction(
        @Valid
        @RequestBody req: SomeRequest
    ): RegisterRes {
        ...
    }
}
```

Inside the requestBody I use the NotBlank validation on this field:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.*

data class SomeRequest(
    @NotBlank(message = "Field is mandatory.")
    val field: String
)
```

However, the field always passes validation when I pass it a json object with an empty string:

```
{ 
    "field": "" 
}
```

What's going wrong here?

---

Additional info:

The following starter to enable validation:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I've even tried adding a whole bunch of other validators, all with the same result that the field always passes validation despite passing en empty string.

```
// Also passes then given ""
@NotBlank(message = "Name is mandatory.")
@NotNull
@NotEmpty
@Size(min = 1)
val field: String,
```

Comment: can you add your import statements as well, it will help SO members to replicate the issue?

Comment: Sure, imports added.

Comment: works for me, only difference is I am using java instead of kotlin

Comment: Turns out that was the difference. For Kotlin data classes we need to write "@field:NotBlank".

Comment: I think annotation usage was wrong in your case, https://kotlinlang.org/docs/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that for Kotlin, we need to annotate each "Java" constraint with @field. E.g.:

```
@field:NotBlank
```

Custom validators written in Kotlin don't need this.